# Ubuntu phone screen only shows intermittently

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, screen

My meizu mx4 is not working after the last update. It switches on and runs as normal, but the screen turns off as the lock screen appears- it then switches back on for a few seconds every few minutes, until I touch the screen. Then it switches off again. I had to reinstall the recovery, and return to the stable channel. This should automatically reinstall the stable version, and I believe it did, but there is no change. Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: I can do very little without the screen on. I have changed from stable to devel to rc proposed and back. But I cant apply any updates via the system updater, and I cant back up everything, it wont mount, I think I need to have the screen on to mount. any help with any of these would be useful. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I had suspected a brightness problem - as this problem had happened to me with android. I tried the development channel and was able to very dimly see the screen. Turned the brightness up from minimum, and problem solved.ta

Comment: As you have found the fix, please mark this question as resolves with the tick next to your answer.